# SharePoint: How to make links in a web part inactive

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have have a calendar web part that I am displaying on an anonymous SharePoint page.

I would like to be able to make all the links in that web part inactive.
Right now, when I click something it takes me to the login page.

Can't have that, boss doesn't want them to see that page.

So I'd like it if I could just have it do nothing when they click on these links.

Is there a way to deactivate all the 's in just the web part ? (I am thinking CSS)
Or does anyone know another way to do it? Is it possible for me to put some kind of a layer over top of the web part that would essentially intercept or block the clicks?

Thanks for your time!! I am really desperate right now, this was due yesterday

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2):

you should see if you can do it via CSS or JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('CLASS OF WP').find('a').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you render links from code behind using asp:HyperLink control, you can disable them

then

myLink.Enable = false;